# Receiving alert when django migrations fail to run

Tags: python, django, sentry, datadog

Currently working on a Django application. The way we apply migrations right now is the following:

- Merging a PR to the main branch
- Triggering a GitHub action to release the new changes to our production environment.

The issue here is that there are some times that the migration issues are not caught during the development and we end up releasing new code, but the migrations fail to run.

How would we be able to set up an alert when the migrations fail to run. It could be a Datadog alert, Sentry alert, or a GitHub action. Feel free to propose and solution.

Thank you very much in advance.